# How should I extend the TTL of a document in Azure CosmosDB using the Python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working with a Cosmos DB database with the SQL API. I have a container with TTL policy of 6 months. When a certain action is taken, my code receives an id and need to extend the deletion time for the item with that id in that container to now + 6 months. What is the recommended way to do this? An empty upsert?

- I can assume the document exists.
- The documents only need to be deleted in approximately six months. I'm not worried about exact timing.
- I'm using the [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.containerproxy). I looked through the documentation, but I could not find anything like an "extend" operation.
- Should I not be leveraging the TTL? Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change to a different TTL on that particular item, just add or update the `'ttl'` field to the desired number of seconds.

example copied straight from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-time-to-live?tabs=python-sdk#reset-time-to-live-using-an-sdk):

```
item = container.read_item(
    item='SO05',
    partition_key='CO18009186470'
)

# Update ttl to 2 hours
item['ttl'] = 60 * 60 * 2 

container.replace_item(
    item='SO05',
    body=item
)
```

basically it adds those seconds to the `'_ts'` field to set the time of deletion

Answer (score 1):

Any update on the document resets the timestamp of that document (the `_ts` property).

The TTL basically acts based on that value.

So in your case, a simple Replace operation over that document would reset the timestamp so it would effectively be deleted 6 months after this last update.